# How to protect a global object which has non-const methods

Tags: c++

I need to expose an instance of my Params class as a global object in a single threaded application.

As a safety measure, I want to prevent client code from inadvertently over-writing the object itself. However, I cannot use a const qualifier (as in the example below) because some of the class methods are non-const.

This class may be re-instantiated in other parts of the code, so I want to avoid changing it's internals to suit this particular need, e.g. by using a singleton design pattern or applying the mutable qualifier to certain data members.

The only solution I can think of is a simple wrapper class whose single data member is a mutable Params object but this seems like a horrible solution for such a simple requirement.

I'm not au fait with the latest advances in C++, so perhaps someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

```
// params.h

class Params
{
  ..
};

extern const Params params;

// params.cpp

#include "params.h"

const Params params;  // no good because class has mutable methods
```

Comment: "I cannot use a const qualifier (as in the example below) because some of the class methods are non-const." => If they don't modify the object make them const. If they modify the object, why should someone be allowed to call them on your global object (you said you don't want someone to Change the object)?

Comment: Do you mean that there are parts of code that should not change `Params` object and there are parts of code that can change, and that you want to protect object changing in the former parts?

Comment: _"As a safety measure, I want to prevent client code from inadvertently over-writing the object itself. "_ This seems to be the crux of your problem, but you haven't really explained what you mean by it. What kind of "over-writing" are you worried about? Assigning to it? Calling its non-const member functions? ... something else?

Comment: It sounds like you should probably implement the access layer that you described in the question and offer only that interface to your client code. I can't fault that design choice given what you've written in the question. It won't protect the object from being "overwritten", but it can certainly protect it from unwanted calls to its mutators.

Comment: My params object will be used extensively throughout the code base, so I just want to prevent it from being inadvertently over-written and causing hard-to-track bugs. While its non-const methods modify the object internals, this is done in a safe controlled fashion

Comment: just to clarify: when I talk about "over-writing" the object, I mean that it is "replaced in its entirety" with some kind of assignment operation; while calling one of its non-const methods will over-write some internal data (in a controlled fashion), it does not replace the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a mutable object that cannot be overwritten you could make the class's `operator=` private/protected.

Comment: Making it non-assignable might be a good idea, but what advantage does the pointer have over the OP's simple non-const global object?

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking there.

Comment: I thought of this already but unfortunately I wish the class to be assignable in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest wrapping the global `Param` object with non-member functions in an appropriate namespace and then implementing those functions using a `Param` object that is private to the implementation.

Something along the lines of:

GlobalParam.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace GlobalParam
{
   void setParam1(Args ...);
   void setParam2(Args ...);

   Type1 getParam1();
   Type2 getParam2();

   // etc.
}
```

GlobalParam.cc:

```
#include "GlobalParam.h"

namespace GlobalParam
{
   // Provide a function that returns a reference
   // to the global Param object. All functions make use of
   // this object. This function is not exposed to the users of
   // the API.
   Param& getParam()
   {
      static Param param;
      return param;
   }

   void setParam1(Args ... args) { getParam().setParam1(args...); }
   void setParam2(Args ... args) { getParam().setParam2(args...); }

   Type1 getParam1() { return getParam().getParam1(); }
   Type2 getParam2() { return getParam().getParam2(); }

   // etc.
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing we end up having to do. Its a real pity that C++ does not offer a more elegant solution

Comment: @rvjc, got to make best use of the tools available to us :)